# shiny widget smaller than application width, how do i make the padding to either side not white?

Tags: r, shiny

my plot below has padding between subplots or padding to the top/bottom or left/right depending on sizing the app window, and i want this to be the same gray background as the app rather than white.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)



ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    
    body = dashboardBody(
        
        fluidRow(
            plotOutput("test",  width = '100%'), align="center"
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    
    set.seed(NULL)
    numPlots <- sample(1:5, 1)
    plot <- sort(rep(seq(1:numPlots), 10))
    d <- data.frame(A = runif(10*numPlots, 0, 10), B = runif(10*numPlots, 0, 10), C = plot)
    
    
    
    matchingGray <- rgb(236/255, 240/255, 245/255)  #best guess using screenshot and then dropper in another tool
    
    g <- list()
    for (p in 1:numPlots)
    {
        g[[p]] <- ggcorrplot(corr = cor(d %>% filter(C == p) %>% select(A,B))) +
            theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = matchingGray, linetype = "blank"))
    }
    
    
    
    output$test <- renderPlot({
        
        gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = g, ncol = length(g))
        
    })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

disregard the silly data giving nonsense correlations, this is just a simple place holder to get at the heart of the issue.  having a variable number of subplots is key though... try running the app multiple times to see the implications on the padding.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(

  header = dashboardHeader(),

  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),

  body = dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
             plotOutput("test",  width = '100%'), align="center"
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$test <- renderPlot({
    ggcorrplot(corr = cor(data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(2,4,8))), outline.color = "green") +
      #theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = rgb(1,0,0)))
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "beige",
                                   colour = "black",
                                   size = 2
      ))+
      theme(plot.margin = margin(25, 24, 22, 22, "mm"))   ### beige color fill area expanded

  }, width=450, height="auto")
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: i don't think this fixes the white space, if my app window is very wide, there's still white to the left or right.  or if my app window is very tall, there's white above and below.  also, i want my plot to be as wide as it can be, not limited to 1/3 of the available width (4/12) if it could be wider (for the given height)

Comment: to be clear the white is a bit subtle, but my app background defaults to a light gray and it's a clear difference than the white of these widget "paddings".  if your app background defaults to white you wouldn't notice the padding

Comment: the padding argument in the theme didn't really help with the color.  i updated the post with some screenshots to make more clear what i mean.  hope that helps, thanks for the replies so far.

Comment: With `renderPlot({}, width=450, height="auto")`, I do not see the white space on either side even when you expand or shrink the windows width.

Comment: thank you!  sorry i think i focused on your theme margin specification... the width and height for the render plot seems to make all the difference, i didn't pay attention to that after your first post.  thanks for being persistent and following up with more comments!  i was really battling with this, thank you for the help!!!

Comment: ach... sorry spoke too soon.  i updated the problem to better reflect my real situation, where i have a variable number of plots drawn and so i don't want to fix the width of my renderPlot.  i also like the variable padding done by grid.arrange to best space things out... i just want the background color to not be white.

Comment: Please note that my solution was for one plot you had in your initial question.  Now, your are using `grid.arrange()`.  This requires a different solution and probably one of the solutions already available in SO (just google it) will meet your need.  You should really post it as a new question, if none of them solve your issue.

Comment: yes you're right... i was hoping there was some common margin color or something that could be changed... that both grid.arrange was showing and my original example (an attempt to keep the problem simple).  was hoping there's just some fill or some parameter i can set to change the white color.  will do some more googling and follow your advice if i can't find the answer.